# Stop reftex-toc from opening a new window if only one window is currently open

Tags: window-splitting, reftex-mode

Currently when I choose an entry from RefTex's table of contents (opened using the `C-c =` keybinding), if I only have a single window open, the chosen file is opened in a new window to the right of the current document.
I read the documentation for `reftex-toc` but couldn't find a way how to replace the file of the current window when pressing the `ret` key instead of opening a new window.

Is this possible? If yes, can anyone be so kind to share the code how to do it?

Edit: The document I am using is a multi-file. The new section I choose is in another file than the one I am currently in. For example, if I am in `main.tex` and I choose the Introduction section, the file `Sections/introduction.tex` is opened in a new window.

The below is the settings I have in my init.el in relation to LaTeX

```
(use-package auctex
  :defer t
  :ensure t
  :config
  (setq TeX-auto-save t)
  (setq TeX-parse-self t)
  (setq-default TeX-master nil)
  (setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
  ;; Set default reference format to \ref
  (setq reftex-refstyle "\\ref")) ; Set default reference format to \ref

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
```

Comment: If I have a single window open with a LaTeX file, and call the table of contents `C-c =`, after I pick the heading I want to go to and press return, the table of contents disappears and I return to having a single window with the original file displayed. I think this is the behaviour you want; if so, it should be the default already!

Comment: If what @Tyler indicates is true then (1) check, by starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file) and (2) if that does what you want then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Tyler do you have a multi-file project? I should have said that in the description. Let me update it.